# I can't put my email in when i try to sign in

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Every time I try to sign in like when you restart your phone I go to the play store and I press existing I when I do my email and password it says I can't sign in. And its an ice cream sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

Check your google account credentials on google.com when/if those are correct then go to settings - scroll down to user and backup section and select accounts - select google and redo your google account settings. After that turn syn on through the top drag down menu and everything should function correctly.